# How to provide LinkedService with a parameter value from Mapping Dataflow?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-mapping-data-flow

I am doing a SQL Azure Database as a datasource in a mapping dataflow. The parameter KeyVaultConnectionString should be dynamic. Se picture 1.

My problem is that I am unable to fiugure out how to provide the value from mapping dataflow. I have tried different things like @pipeline.parameters.ConnString but thats just crap.

[image]

[image]

Thanks.

***** UPDATE (28-09-2022) *****

I forgot to explain that the flow is a Flowlet. The picture below shows the Flowlet that uses a SQL Server as a Source. I choose Inline dataset but I am not able to pass variable from the "outer" mapping data flow to the datasource.

[image]

Comment: Did you check running the dataflow without testing the connection? From where are you passing the value of the Connection string to your linked service?

Comment: Yes it is not a problem to debug the flow. I can set the the parameter value in the Debug Setting for the flow. But where do I set the value in the Source activity of the flow?

Comment: Can you please clarify this: You want to set the value for your parameter `ConnString` from the dataflow source? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Correct, Is that not possible? I thought that when I choose the LinkedService from the DropDown menu I would be presented with a parameter field according to the parameters that I declared in the linked service.

Answer (score 0):

For `inline` dataset as source in dataflows, the parameter option is not showing as a separate section. I tried to use the following linked service where I am using the linked service parameter to give my blob storage name.

[image]

- Now when I use this in the dataflow source as inline dataset and try to test connection, it fails.

[image]

- However, complete configuring the dataflow with required transformations and use `dataflow` activity in azure data factory pipeline. Here it shows the parameter to which the necessary value should be passed to linked service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are in design/debug mode from the data flow designer, parameters will show in the right-panel when you click "Debug Settings" on the top of your designer window.

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes I am able to debug. One thing I forgot to explain is that the flow is a flowlet. I just updated the question with additional explaination.

Comment: Kromer, in your video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVdeBFiiJNQ&t=115s you explain the flowlet very nicely. However, when you create the Mapping Dataflow where you consume the Flowlet as a Source, how are going about bringing into the Flowlet eg. a dynamic connectionstring that a LinkedService could use like eg. @LinkedService().connectionstring?